# Make typography automatically add quotation marks in MS Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word (Microsoft Word for Office 365 in my case) typographies can be pre-defined in document templates, so that formatting can be set by highlighting some text and clicking the typography (`Home` tab -> `Typographies` box).

One thing I can't find, with no luck from searching the web and MS support site, is how to make a typography not just add formatting (color, font, size, lining, indentation...) but **how to make a typography add symbols**.

Specifically, I would like quotation marks `"text"`, apostrophes `'text'` etc. added around my highlighting (before and after). E.g. if I highlight the words `To be or not to be` in this sentence:

> The famous line To be or not to be is from Hamlet

and click the typography I would like the result to automatically become:

> The famous line "To be or not to be" is from Hamlet

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do that with typographies (I think my version of Word calls them "Styles"), but perhaps a macro will give you what you need. I made this as a macro:

```
Sub Quotes()
'
' Quotes Macro
'
'
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.TypeText Text:=""""
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    Selection.TypeText Text:=""""
End Sub
```

I then ran that macro (you can associate it with a button or a keyboard shortcut if you'd like) and it added quotation marks around the selected text.

Note: depending on your settings, this might not have the spacing you want at either end of the quotation. Word tries to be helpful and adjusts spacing when cutting out a word or words. To make it do what you want, you'll probably have to disable that feature.

> Word options->Advanced->Cut, Copy and Paste->Use smart cut and paste->Settings->Adjust  sentence and word spacing automatically.

(For super-bonus points, you can make the macro record the state of that setting, turn it off, do the cut-quote-paste-quote stuff, and then restore the saved state of the setting.)